# angularjs variable in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have this:

```
$scope.customers = 'blabla';
```

is there a way to do this:

```
var entityId = 'customers';

$scope.entityId = 'blabla';
```

and pass the variable entityId to create the $scope.customers;

can that be done?

Comment: you mean like `$scope[entityId] = "blablah";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. and its about javascript and not angularjs

```
$scope[entityId] = 'blabla';
```